# Updating computed properties in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple app in which a user hasMany notifications, notifications have a readAt attribute, and I want to display a count of unread notifications. I have the following code:

User model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

    notifications: DS.hasMany('notification', {async: true}),

    unreadNotifications: function(){
        return this.get('notifications').filter(function(notification){
            return notification.get('readAt') === null;
        });
    }.property('notifications')

});
```

Template:

```
<span class="badge messages-count">
    {{currentUser.unreadNotifications.length}}
</span>
```

I am pushing in new notifications dynamically. This works perfectly if I set it to count just notifications (i.e. {{currentUser.notifications.length}} but the computed unreadNotifications property does not update unless the page is refreshed. Have I missed some way to bind these data properly?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `notifications` is an array-type property, you need to use `@each` syntax as defined [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/).

So, your `unreadNotifications` property should be defined as follows:

```
unreadNotifications: function(){
    return this.get('notifications').filter(function(notification){
        return notification.get('readAt') === null;
    });
}.property('notifications.@each.readAt')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the problem - another Ember gotcha solved!